# How to use relationship inside another relationship of other model?

Tags: laravel

I want to use `public function scheduleTime()` to check sechudle_time inside `newsLetterSentOn()` of News Model.
If this can be done,please help me regarding this.Thank you.

This is News Model

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Newsletter\Entities;
use Brexis\LaravelWorkflow\Traits\WorkflowTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

/**
 * This is for storing  news
 * Class News
 * @package Modules\Newsletter\Entities
 */
class News extends Model {

    use WorkflowTrait;
    protected $table = 'news_info';
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'header', 'description', 'status', 'created_by', 'media_url', 'media_thumbnail', 'media_type'
    ];

    public function newsLetterSentOn() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Newsletter::class,'news_newsletters','news_id','newsletter_id')
            ->whereHas('scheduleTime', function($q){
                $q->where('schedule_time', '<', date("Y-m-d h:i:s", time()));
            });
    } 
}
```

This is Newsletter Model

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Newsletter\Entities;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Newsletter extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'newsletters';
    protected $hidden = ['pivot'];

    protected $fillable = [];
    public function scheduleTime()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ScheduleTime::class,'id','newsletter_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: No. That is not my question.

Comment: Please clarify on the "check". I'm sure what you want can be done. just don't get what you are trying to do. You just want the method to return `ScheduleTime` data within the date ?

Comment: yes. ScheduleTime of Newsletter

Answer (score 1):

You can get nested relationship with dot notation like so:

```php
$news = News::with(['newsLetterSentOn.scheduleTime' => function($q)
   $q->where('schedule_time', '<', date("Y-m-d h:i:s", time()));
])->find($id);
```

Then you can access it through `$news` like normal.

```php
$news->newsLetterSenton->scheduleTime;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but I have to check using scheduleTime as I mentioned in the question.
this query->>
->whereHas('scheduleTime', function($q){
                $q->where('schedule_time', '<', date("Y-m-d h:i:s", time()));
            });

Comment: @RaviPratapSinghyour original question doesn't include this comment, so you should edit it. I've edit my answer, you can use it that way.

Comment: please check question first. I am using this in model. not in controller

Comment: @RaviPratapSingh please clarify more ? Your method is a setup for relationship. If you just want to 'check' i don;t know what you meant by check, then you should just use normal method instead of a relationship one.

Comment: $past = News::with('newsLetterSentOn')->get();
In above query I want all newsletters which have schedule_time less then current time.
this logic is defined in newsLetterSentOn method inside model.
please confirm if you got my words.